# Rails - Update object from params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'd like to know if there is a way to bind params to an existing object in order to edit it. I'd like to do something like this, but to edit the object :

```
@object = Object.new(params[:object])
```

So something like :

```
@object = Object.find(params[:object_id])
@object.edit(params[:object])
```

`params[:object]` comes from a `form_for`

Any idea ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use

```
@object.assign_attributes(params[:object])
```

or

```
@object.attributes = params[:object]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just remember the update method. Is it the same ?

Comment: Not exactly, `update` saves the record after assigning the attributes, unlike the methods above which only do the assignment.

Comment: I meant for the assignation. I want to save the records right after so I think `update` is the method I need. I just need to figure out why I get a `ForbiddenAttributesError`

Comment: @Aeradriel, its because of strong parameters which where added in Rails 4. Basically you need to sanitise the parameters hash in your controller before you use it for mass assignment (assigning multiple parameters at once). http://blog.sensible.io/2013/08/17/strong-parameters-by-example.html http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters

Comment: Yeah I just remember about this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to edit the `params` sending from a `form_for`, you can assign it to a hash and start editing it.

```
@params = params 
# and do whatever to the @params
```

after that you can use the `assign_attributes` as Ahmad Sherif indicated or `new` or `update_attributes` to assign it to a model record.